# Magento - Sales > Order 'Processing' status

Tags: magento, select

Good morning,

We are currently using **Magento** and trying to list '**Processing**' orders as default. 
We have located the status dropdown column but can't figure out how to set '**Processing**' as default.

We would love some help on this,
Thank you.

```
$this->addColumn('status', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Status'),
            'index' => 'status',
            'type'  => 'options',
            'width' => '70px',
            'options' => Mage::getSingleton('sales/order_config')->getStatuses(),
        ));
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little help from Amit Bera we managed to figure this out.

Open - app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php
Find - parent::__construct(); 
and add underneath $this->setDefaultFilter(array('status'=>'processing'));

Worked like a charm.